# Setting a cookie with WEB API 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

im trying to set a cookie from within my WEB API controller. I've followed the following tutorial: [HTTP Cookies in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies)

this is the code i got:

```
[Route("api/user/SetCookie")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage SetCookie()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage respMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new ObjectContent<string[]>(new string[] {"value1", "value2"}, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            };
            CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "123")
            {
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1),
                Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host,
                Path = "/"
            };
            respMessage.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
            return respMessage;
        }
```

the problem is I can't see that any cookie is being set. I've used fiddler,postman and chrome debugger and no cookie is being presented. Any help in fixing this issue is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the example under "structured cookie data" header?

Comment: @IgorŠevo yes i have, same result.

Comment: in the response headers I found `Set-Cookie: session-id=123; expires=Fri, 20 Nov 2015 09:52:24 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/` in fiddler

Comment: Are you sure that the server and client time are in sync?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I find this as well but i can't view the cookie. Shouldn't the cookie show up in chrome under Resources/Cookies/ ?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is i want to set a cookie after a successful login attempt and the cookie stores the username so i can access it. How can I then set a cookie and access the information that's within the cookie?